# How to actively track distance using CLLocationManager

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I would like to know, how to actively (and precisely) track the distance traveled by the user using CLLocationManager. Currently my code looks like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation*)oldLocation {
    totalDistance += [newLocation distanceFrom:oldLocation] / kMilesToMeters;
}
```

However, as I checked with my odometer, the results are quite inaccurate. Is there a more accurate way of actively calculating distance while the user is moving?

Thank you

Comment: Did u set the desiredAccuracy and the distanceFilter ?

Answer (score 1):

GPS is very inaccurate. Sometimes it can "teleport" you somewhere else and then take you back. So first thing you have to do is to filter out all the false data. You can ignore locations that change too frequently: e.g. GPS tells that you are at p1(x,y) and in a moment it tells that you're at p2(x+20m, y+10m) after several seconds it tells you that your location is p3(x+2m, y+3m). So obviously that p2 is probably false location and you can ignore it.

Also a good idea is not to use locations directly to calculate distance but progressively approximate those values (maybe least squares method is good for you, or if you like hard math then you can look at Kalman filter ).